# Accessing a variable from another class in swift

Tags: swift, class, variables

I've been trying to Google this one for hours now and I feel like I'm going in circles. I am trying to call the preferences that I set up in my preferences window in my main app.

My preferences window is set up like this:

```
class GeneralPreferencesController: NSViewController, CCNPreferencesWindowControllerProtocol {
let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let prefs1 = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let prefs2 = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let prefs3 = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var Test1: AnyObject? = " "

@IBAction func SavePref(sender: AnyObject) {

    prefs2.setObject(Name.stringValue, forKey: "Person")

    Test1 = prefs2.valueForKey("Person")

}
```

And then I need to call this preference in my main window to send an email on a button click. This is the part where I am stuck. I set up the Test1 variable so that I could easily call the preference, but I can't figure out how to successfully call this in my AppDelegate.swift document. Can someone assist me in this? All the other answers on here have me super confused :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standart defaults can be accessed from anywhere in you application. So if you successfully wrote "Name" for "Person" key the next code should work for you in delegate:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("Person")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was EXACTLY what I needed!